# Ubuntu 18.04 EFI boot sequence confusing

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 18.04

After a little bit of researching I thought while the system is booting UEFI first loads **/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi** with a bunch GRUB modules from a separate directory, then reads **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** and so on.

But as I see the case is quite the opposite. It seems the first step is to open **/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI**. As I know **BOOTX64.EFI** is the complete GRUB with all the necessary modules in it. After removing **BOOTX64.EF**I, then comes the **startup.nsh** into the picture. When it contains the right line "**\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi**", Ubuntu will start.

**My questions:**

- Why isn't **grubx64.efi** comes first? Because each UEFI implementation
  is different than another?
- Or because multiple bootloaders can be on the same ESP?

(The OS sits in a Virutalbox VM.)

Comment: Do not know VMs. But UEFI only boots external devices from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. And internal drives can boot that, some use that as a fallback or hard drive entry. A few use that as the primary internal boot entry. Many also only boot by description or only "Windows Boot Manager", but then  the fallback entry can be used. the .nsh file is normally an UEFI boot script. What is in yours? What brand/model system?

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion now I'm closer to understand the whole process. Also I found a good summary: https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/